# Git command posts my entire desktop to repo

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I only want to post a single directory to a repo (using bitbucket), yet whenever I try a git push command, I end up pushing my entire desktop directory. Is there a way to reset whatever I have waiting to be committed when I make a push? I've tried to Google this but none of the examples did what I wanted. Here are my commands I used (Bitbucket tutorial):

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote add origin https://(address here)
git push -u origin --all   # to push changes for the first time
```

Comment: is your repo initialised as a git repo?

Comment: Yes, Bitbucket sets this up for you

Comment: Well you have to do an `git --init` first before you can commit and push afterwards. I suggest you to read this: http://rogerdudler.github.com/git-guide/

Comment: This is already provided for you... My issue is that I have previous "adds" that are added when I push to my repo. So I'm pushing everything I've ever added when using git commands.

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
git checkout -- <file>
```

The dash dash basically removes the files from staging.

Edit: "Git status" will list all the files and their relationship to git. It'll show some commands for how to remove and add them to the staging list. Then once you're satisfied with the staging, you push.

```
git status
```